# Layout Animation not working on Android (create() method)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm using LayoutAnimation for animating my `<View>`. I toggle it with:

```
LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
this.showView = !this.showView;
```

but the animation is not working at the moment of create, only when the View disappears. 
(iOS works perfect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably something wrong with the loading of text that was displayed in my View. Now I'm loading the text from the JSON file and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code segment for Android.

```js
import  { UIManager, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
...
if (Platform.OS === "android") {
     UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
     UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}
```

Comment: I did it, but as I said when I hide my View there is animation, the problem is only when I want to show the View it appears without animation.

Comment: this solution works for me,thanks